# Is the Delta distribution a continuous functional on $H^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

While it is easy to see that $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ are Hölder $1/2$-continuous, I started wondering whether this implies that $\delta_x(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$ is continuous as a functional

$$\delta_x:H^1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}?$$

I believe it is false, but do not know a counterexample.

Since it was asked in the comments: Continuity means $$\left\lvert \varphi(x) \right\rvert \lesssim \left\lVert \varphi \right\rVert_{H^1}.$$

Comment: What would continuity mean in this case? Also, ask this at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DIrk Well, $\left\lvert \varphi(x) \right\rvert \lesssim \left\lVert \varphi \right\rVert_{H^1}$ or course.

Comment: Which norm? What do you know about embeddings of H^1?

Comment: I know Morrey's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey's_inequality

Comment: .. and how is $|\varphi(x)|$ related to the left-hand side in this inequality..?

Comment: Perhaps ... the dual of $H^1$ is BMO, and $\delta$ is not an element of BMO ??

Comment: It appears that the question is rather simple, but not altogether trivial.

Comment: As per comments below, could you please clarify what space $H^1$ is supposed to be - Sobolev, Hardy, ???

Comment: At the level of abstract nonsense, once you know that all the elements of $H^1$ are continuous, the delta distribution basically has to be continuous.  If $H^1$ functions are continuous (have continuous versions) then the inclusion map $H^1(\mathbb{R}) \to C([-1,1])$ is well defined.  Morally, any everywhere-defined linear map between Banach spaces which didn't need the Axiom of Choice to construct, must be continuous.  (More concretely, use the closed graph theorem to show continuity.)  And the delta distribution is obviously continuous on $C([-1,1])$.

Comment: Though of course it is best to work explicitly and get the right constant if you can.  But this shows in advance that it's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:=\varphi$, $a:=\|f\|_2$, $b:=\|f'\|_2$, so that $\|f\|_{H^1}=a+b$; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) for the definition of $H^k$. Without loss of generality, $x=0$. For all $y\in[0,1]$, we have 
$$|f(y)-f(0)|\le\int_0^y|f'(t)|dt\le\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt\le\sqrt{\int_0^1|f'(t)|^2 dt}\le b,$$
by H\"older's inequality, whence $|f(0)|\le b+|f(y)|$. So, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 f(0)^2\le\int_0^1(b+|f(y)|)^2dy&
\le2\int_0^1(b^2+|f(y)|^2)dy\le2(b^2+a^2)\\
&\le2(a+b)^2=2\|f\|_{H^1}^2,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
whence 
\begin{equation}
 |f(0)|\le\sqrt2\,\|f\|_{H^1},
\end{equation}
as desired.

Using here the interval $[0,a/b]$ instead of $[0,1]$, one can improve the above inequality to 
\begin{equation}
 |f(0)|\le2\sqrt{ab}=2\sqrt{\|f\|_2\,\|f'\|_2}\le \|f\|_{H^1}. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Perhaps a reference for this norm of $H^1(\mathbb R)$ should be provided.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Done.

Comment: OK we have a quandary here.  I understood $H^1$ to be a Hardy space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space not a Sobolev space.  I guess the OP has to tell us what he means: this is a classic case of "not clear what you are asking".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : The OP wrote $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ rather than $H^1(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: And part 6 in my link defines Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Do you mean the real Hardy space for $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : I don't see the notation $H^p(\mathbb{R})$ at part 6 of your link.

Comment: True, that link never puts any domain into the notation.  It defines "Hardy space $H^p$ on the real vector space $\mathbb R^n$", so I thought our OP here meant "Hardy space $H^1$ on the real vector space $\mathbb R$".

Comment: Nitpick: assuming this is Sobolev, $\|f\|_{H^1}$ isn't $a+b$ but rather $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  The argument still works but some of the numerical constants may change.

Comment: @NateEldredge : As I recall from the PDE course taken in 1970 or 1971 from S. V. Uspenskii, who I think was a student of Sobolev and anyway worked in Sobolev's department   (http://a-server.math.nsc.ru/IM/Awards1.asp), the definition of the Sobolev norm was of the $a+b$ kind, but I can't be quite sure at this point. :-) Of course the two norms, $a+b$ and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, are equivalent anyway.

Comment: Well, if you want to get a Hilbert space, I think you're forced to use $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  For $W^{1,p}$ with $p \ne 2$ then it makes much less difference.

Comment: Right, for a Hilbert space this seems to be the only choice.